# Extract excel row based on condition

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Hi I have an Excel table column a below

```
   RowNo    ID  CancelledBy
   1    12345   Provider
   2    12345   Provider
   3    12345   Patient
   4    12345   Patient
   5    12345   Patient
   6    12345   Provider
   7    12345   Patient
   8    12345   Provider
   9    54321   Patient
  10    54321   Provider
  11    54321   Provider
  12    54321   Patient
  13    54321   Provider
```

From the above table I would like to pick those rows if a row contain "provider" and the immediate next row contain "Patient" then I would like to extract the two rows for that patient. 
Basically "provider" rows followed by "patient" rows like the below.

```
 RowNo  ID  CancelledBy
  2  12345  Provider
  3  12345  Patient
  6  12345  Provider
  7  12345  Patient
 11  54321  Provider
 12  54321  Patient
```

Is there a excel formula/vbscript or macro that will do this. I tried all day but no joy.

thanks

Comment: Why aren't you including rows 8 and 9 in your output? It seems to meet your criteria...

Comment: What formula(s) did you try? Couldn't you use an `If()` formula with `And()` perhaps?

Comment: Hi CMArg, Rows 8 and 9 not in output because its different patient ID

   8    **12345**
   9    **54321**

Comment: So there is one more criteria... Check my edited answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited** The following might help. Data is supposed to be in sheet "MyData" (with a command button), results are written in sheet "Extracted". Code can be shortened, but I leave it hard coded for readability.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim k As Integer

    lLastRow = Worksheets("MyData").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    k = 1
    For i = 1 To lLastRow
        If ((Worksheets("MyData").Cells(i, 3) = "Provider" And Worksheets("MyData").Cells(i + 1, 3) = "Patient") And (Worksheets("MyData").Cells(i, 2).Value = Worksheets("MyData").Cells(i + 1, 2).Value)) Then

            Worksheets("Extracted").Cells(k, 1) = Worksheets("MyData").Cells(i, 1)
            Worksheets("Extracted").Cells(k, 2) = Worksheets("MyData").Cells(i, 2)
            Worksheets("Extracted").Cells(k, 3) = Worksheets("MyData").Cells(i, 3)

            Worksheets("Extracted").Cells(k + 1, 1) = Worksheets("MyData").Cells(i + 1, 1)
            Worksheets("Extracted").Cells(k + 1, 2) = Worksheets("MyData").Cells(i + 1, 2)
            Worksheets("Extracted").Cells(k + 1, 3) = Worksheets("MyData").Cells(i + 1, 3)

            k = k + 2
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

if "CancelledBy" is in column C you can use this formula in D2

=IF(OR(AND(C2="provider",D1=1),AND(C2="Provider",C3="Patient")),1,0)

then copy to all rows from D3 to D14

All rows you need will be equal to 1 then you can filter column D with 1 value.

I hope this can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your data is in col `A` and `B` starting from `row 2`. use these formulas

C2 =AND(B2="Provider",B3="Patient")

Fill formula all the way down

```
D2 =IF(MOD(ROW(D2)-ROW($D$2),2)=0,1/AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(--($C$2:$C$14)*(ROW($C$2:$C$14))*(ROW($C$2:$C$14)>1)),1),1)

D3 =IF(MOD(ROW(D3)-ROW($D$2),2)=0,1/AGGREGATE(14,6,1/(--($C$2:$C$14)*(ROW($C$2:$C$14))*(ROW($C$2:$C$14)>D2-1)),1),D2+1)
```

Fill `D3` down until you start getting `#NUM`. This populates all the row numbers that you need to get the data from.

```
E2 =INDEX($A$1:$B$14,D2,1)
F2 =INDEX($A$1:$B$14,D2,2)
```

Fill `E2:F2` all the way down. This should populate your desired result.

**Edit:**

Revised INDEX formulas
[image: Screenshot]